# Compile scss to scss and don't apply functions that are not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, cloudinary, gulp-sass, node-sass

There's some ruby-on-rails project with a lot of scss files. Images stored in cloudinary.com cdn. Inside source scss files there's such construction:

```
.test {
  background-image: cloudinary-url("somepic.png",$width:10,$height:10);
}
```

Then we try to compile all scss files into one large scss.
Cloudinary gem should substitute correct url during deploy.

This all worked before update, with old node, gulp-sass and node-sass libraries, but now we have to use new versions. And now it does not work.

Here's the error: 
`Function cloudinary-url doesn't support keyword arguments`

The function cloudinary-url really is not defined during compile. The goal is to somehow skip processing of undefined functions. So that in compiled scss file we should have the same `background-image: cloudinary-url("somepic.png",$width:10,$height:10);` as we have in source files. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're compiling the sass using Node and later include the result in a Rails app. Maybe what you need is to define a custom function in the node-sass configuration of your Node application.
Something like (*untested!*):

```
functions: {
  "cloudinary-url": function( publicId, sassOptions) {
    var options = {}
    var i, l, key, value;

    for (i = 0, l = sassOptions.getLength(); i < l; i++) {
      key = sassOptions.getKey(i);
      value = sassOptions.getValue(i);
      options[key] = value
    }
    return new sass.types.String(cloudinary.url(publicId.getValue(), options));
  }
}
```

Include and configure the [Cloudinary Node SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudinary) in your Node app that compiles the sass. See also [node-sass samples](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/test/api.js#L607-619).

If however you wish to pass the `cloudinary-url` as is to the Rails app, I suggest adding it as a comment and replacing it in post-processing (e.g. by using [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace)).

```
.test {
  background-image: url(dummy.jpg); //cloudinary-url("somepic.png",$width:10,$height:10);
}
```

... and in gulp, after compiling the sass ...

```
.pipe(replace('url(dummy.jpg); //', ''))
```